# Are there any free pharmacophore modelling software?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I would like to know if there is any free and relatively updated software to getting started in pharmacophore modelling.

Comment: Have you checked the ones listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharmacophore ?

Comment: I think they are not free though